# GET 404 S3 AWS React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-status-code-404, amazon-cloudfront

I use S3 bucket for the front end. My error and home page are set to index.html. It used to work perfectly fine, but now for some reason, it gives this error. I tried creating an error reference in CloudFront but it does not work.

When I run it all in local, it all works fine. I tried deploying to S3 by dropping the build folder as well as from cli.

I get this error upon loading the home page of the website and if I change the links like /register or /login etc. It loads the page like the login page but does not send the data (cannot log in).

```
GET https://api.website.com/login 404
```

Here I printed the error to the console

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /login <pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you `GET https://api.website.com/login.html`?

Comment: @Nick blank white screen and the same error with .html in the console: GET https://api.website.com/login.html 404

Comment: GET https://api.website.com/build/login.html ?